# Add condition to SNMP request via php

Tags: request, conditional-statements, snmp

I am trying to integrated two systems using SNMP protocol, here is my question:
as you know to get queries from for example MySQL database i have ability to add conditions in query string and get required result, some thing like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a='foo' AND b='bar'
```

is there any possibility to request queries using SNMP with conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you need to select data based on the mib instance or the mib data.

You can select data based on the instance, like:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic 1.2.3.4  ifOperStatus
```

This will give you all interface statuses in a device.

SNMP do not support getting only ifOperStatus = "up", in this case you need to retrieve all instance and make your selection

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic 1.2.3.4  ifOperStatus | grep up
```

Another more over the top solution is to collect the data and store it in a database, then you can use the SQL syntax you mentioned in your question